# Merging 2 dataframes on index and columns

Tags: pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I am really stuck on a merger/ join of 2 dataframes. I would like to merge both on index and columns, here is an example

df1 :

```
         A   B   C
index 1  0   a   b
index 2  a   0   c
index 3  b   c   0
```

df 2 :

```
         B   C   D
index 2  0   c   d
index 3  c   0   e
index 4  d   e   0
```

I would like to get :

```
df3:
         A   B   C   D
index 1  0   a   b   nan
index 2  a   0   c   d
index 3  b   c   0   e
index 4  nan d   e   0
```

I tried many combinations of merge, join, concat and can't find the solution,
could you please help me???
Eternal gratitude!!

Comment: What if there was a mismatch for index 3 / col B? What should be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if you want a real `merge`, i.e. what should happen in case of a mismatch in the overlapping indices.

Assuming there is **no mismatch**, you can [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Output:

```
          A  B  C    D
index1    0  a  b  NaN
index2    a  0  c    d
index3    b  c  0    e
index4  NaN  d  e    0
```